# Java sending Mutliple Files attachment in mailgun

Tags: java, spring, mailgun

I'm trying to send email with mailgun and attaching two files or more with this email:

```
public static JsonNode sendComplexMessage() throws UnirestException {

        HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME + "/messages")
                .basicAuth("api", API_KEY)
                .queryString("from", "Excited User <USER@YOURDOMAIN.COM>")
                .queryString("to", "alice@example.com")
                .queryString("cc", "bob@example.com")
                .queryString("bcc", "joe@example.com")
                .queryString("subject", "Hello")
                .queryString("text", "Testing out some Mailgun awesomeness!")
                .queryString("html", "<html>HTML version </html>")
                .field("attachment", new File("/temp/folder/test.txt"))
                .asJson();

        return request.getBody();
```

This example is from Mailgun Docs, but it send just single file. I need to send multiple emails.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of putting a single file object ,put an arrayList of Files and it's gonna to work like this :

```
.field("attachment", Arrays.asList(file1,file2))
```

you can create a list,iterate over it by loop and then send it

```
List<File> listFiles=new ArrayList<>();
// fill it

.field("attachment", listFiles)
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method but unfortunately in my case, attachments are getting duplicated. Any idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.field("attachment", new File("FILE_NAME"))` again to send one more attachement as shown in below code:

```
public static JsonNode sendComplexMessage() throws UnirestException {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = Unirest.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME + "/messages")
                    .basicAuth("api", API_KEY)
                    .queryString("from", "Excited User <USER@YOURDOMAIN.COM>")
                    .queryString("to", "alice@example.com")
                    .queryString("cc", "bob@example.com")
                    .queryString("bcc", "joe@example.com")
                    .queryString("subject", "Hello")
                    .queryString("text", "Testing out some Mailgun awesomeness!")
                    .queryString("html", "<html>HTML version </html>")

                    // attaching test.txt and test2.txt files
                    .field("attachment", new File("/temp/folder/test.txt"))
                    .field("attachment", new File("/temp/folder/test2.txt"))

                    .asJson();
}
```

Comment: number of files is dynamic maybe they are two, three, more or even one file i think this solution is not suitable for this case

Answer (score 0):

If you have file names in a list you can do this:

```
List<String> attachmentNames = ...
for (String attachmentName : attachmentNames) {
     multipartBody.field("attachment", new File(attachmentName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's late but the version with no File, only InputStream

```java
public class MyEmailAttachment {
    byte[] content;
    String name;
}
```

```java
   String baseUrl = getKey(Configuration.MAILGUN_BASEURL);
        String domain = getKey(Configuration.MAILGUN_DOMAIN);
        String apiKey = getKey(Configuration.MAILGUN_API_KEY);
        String from = getKey(Configuration.MAILGUN_FROM_SENDER);

        String url = baseUrl + "/v3/" + domain + "/messages"; 

        MultipartBody body = Unirest.post(url)
                .basicAuth("api", apiKey)
                .field("from", from)
                .field("to", to) //it's a List<String>
                .field("cc", cc) //it's a List<String>
                .field("subject", subject)
                .field("html", message);

        for (MyEmailAttachment mya : attachments) {
            body.field("attachment", new ByteArrayInputStream(mya.content), mya.name);
        }
                
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = body.asJson();
        //do something with request
```